# Jquery: how do I set the width of a tooltip in relation of its parent div

Tags: jquery-ui

I copied the code from the jquery-page and tryed to modify it to size my tooltips in relation of its parent. I think the code says what I want to do. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ratmalwer/uChnH/32/)

```
$( document ).tooltip({
    position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
            $( this ).css( position );

            // set width of tooltip
            var w = $(this).closest('div').width();
            $(this).css("width",w);
            $(this).css("max-width",w);

            $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "arrow" )
            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a big amount of text. So the tooltip overlaps the content to the right border of the window.

Comment: Here the fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ratmalwer/uChnH/32/) I hope it works (its my first fiddle). Tipps appreciated.